# Is there the simple way to wait (some time) without application freeze?

Tags: .net, timer

For now I've got

```
    if blocker then 
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        do something
```

It's running in the while circle so my whole application is just being freeze. It's also matters for me to do something in Main application thread so that's why I don't create new.

I think that I need to create temporary Timer, add on elapsed event, handle it and then do something but I just want to know if there is some simple solution for it and I don't need to "re-invent a bicycle"?

Comment: Could you explain why you need that wait?

Comment: Wait some time (need for server)

Comment: @Nensha use a background worker task which does the request and asynchronly wait for the answer, then update the gui thread via the dispatcher (Invoke method)

Comment: If you are using single thread, your application is anyways going to wait for the processing of current line before starting next.

Comment: @danish Isee. So that must anyways be an event to "unfreeze" application.

Comment: Your whole app is freezing because you're sleeping the main thread. If you want the UI to still be responsive whilst you're processing some data/waiting on a server response, then you should use a background worker or separate thread to do the long running process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
    private static Timer _timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += TimeEvent;
        _timer.Interval = 5000; 
        _timer.Start(); 

        while (Console.Read() != 'q')
        {
            ;     
        }
    }

    public static void TimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Time event!");
        _timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: yes, that's what I need... but need to convert to F#, hope I can do it myself )

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to reinvent the wheel:

```
// create a timer that waits 10 seconds and start it
Timer timer = new Timer(10 * 1000);
timer.Elapsed += this.TimerElapsed;
timer.Start(); 

public void TimerElapsed(object o, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Timer has elapsed");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class to which you can pass your problem. And call its method through a thread.
and in that class you can make events, so when the class finishes its job, it will raise an event and your app will know that the job is done.

Comment: how that could be better then timer?

Comment: Timer will run on specific time. And thread will raise events.